# Suggest allowing users to select a "title" based on their badges

Tags: feature-request, badges, user-accounts

In one of my game designer moments, it occurred to me that a feature that would be a lot of fun on StackOverflow/StackExchange sites would be allowing users to choose a "title" for themselves based on their badges.  The way this would work would be:

1. The user could select up to three of their badges on a given site to build their title out of.
2. The user could select the order the badge names appeared in within the title.
3. The resulting title would appear with the user's identifying information.  For example, ID blocks with titles might look like:

[image: Modified SE ID block with title: chaos]
[image: Modified SE ID block with title: Jon Skeet]

This serves the purpose of giving users an achievement-based way of customizing their appearance on the site, which people always love, and of increasing the value of badges by giving them additional utility.  I would also give SE flair considerably more personal style.  (One potential use for the functionality, from an answer, is to use titles *only* in flair.)

Badge names which do not seem to lend themselves well to title formation, like "Nice Answer", could be addressed in a number of ways:

1. Ignoring the issue; if people want to construct a title that doesn't make sense, let them.
2. Some badges could have an alternate appearance for title purposes, such as "Revival" becoming "Revivalist".
3. Some badges could be excluded from title usage.
4. Users could be given the ability to specify commas between the elements of their titles, allowing formations like "Nice Answer, Tumbleweed".  (This option is near and dear to my heart because it tends to produce results that sound like the names of ships from [Iain Banks's Culture sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Culture_series).)

If you have suggestions for enhancements to the concept, please post them as answers so they can be voted on.

Comment: But anyone can simply add that same "title" *after* their screen name, no?

Comment: @Bart Kiers: In some sense, but it's not the same at all as having the title capability as a site builtin.  Especially socially.

Comment: How would tag badges be handled?

Comment: @James McNellis: Like any other badge.  So Jon could be a *Legendary c# Guru* if he liked.

Comment: @James McNellis: The reason I wouldn't do that is that one of the most interesting parts of the exercise is seeing what you can do with the limited set of "puzzle pieces" provided by your badges.  Constraints spur creativity.

Comment: Another way to handle nonsense titles would be to specify adjectives and nouns in titles. So you could have _Legendary Epic Generalist_ but not _Generalist Legendary Epic_ or _Guru Generalist Nice Answerer_, or better yet, make them based on the position, so you could have _Reviving Legendary Autobiographer_ or _Reviving Autobiographic Legend_.

Comment: @chaos I'm flattered that you believe my comment is meant to have some relevant impact on the discussion.  I've removed it so no further confusion results.

Comment: +1 because the method of name generation, -1 because it's not really nessesary

Comment: @Farseeker: Good God, we only do things that are *necessary* now?  What sort of excuse for existence is *that*?

Comment: @Ullallulloo: You should post that as an answer. :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that, if such a system existed, Jon Skeet's title would be "Jon Skeet".

Comment: `Talkative Necromancer`... hmmm

Comment: @Benjol: You know you want it.

Comment: So this question now has two votes to close as "noise or pointless", and it just boggles my mind: how enormous of a douchebag do you have to be to use the close button in such total bad faith?  Though it seems likely that one of them was Rich B during his brief window out from under the banhammer today, so that kind of answers that question.  But what in the world was the *other* person thinking?

Comment: @Chaos - the people on the SO team are very good at adding features that are value-add, and I just don't see how this adds value to their primary goal, which is to "make the internet a better place". That said, I wasn't one of the people who voted to close.

Comment: @Farseeker: Adding to the enjoyment people derive from their use of SE sites is a value-add and makes the internet a better place.  Not that that can ever be the sole criterion, of course; features that people may enjoy but that detract from the utility of the site are rightly avoided.  I have to say that most "doesn't add value" arguments you could make about this proposal apply equally to badges themselves, however, since badges are fun psychological fluff and one has to be making SE sites into Srs Bzns and ignoring psychological value as even valid in order to make that sort of argument.

Comment: @Chaos - well, badges encourage participation, so I guess in that regard your idea does have merit

Comment: @Farseeker: It kind of all goes to a fundamental aspect of the SE model that completely escapes the Srs Bzns types: that its success comes from having done a passably good job of structuring activity that improves the world as a *game*.  I only just got Jane McGonigal's *Reality Is Broken*, which is all about that, but if I read through it all the way and find that it doesn't have at least half a chapter devoted to StackOverflow, I'll be very disappointed. (book link: http://www.amazon.com/Reality-Broken-Games-Better-Change/dp/1594202850)

Comment: You already have a user name that seems to serve the same purpose in the image you've shown. Considering that this is not a social networking website, anything else seems superfluous. What are you adding besides noise? And what are "Srz Btns"?

Answer (score 7):

I'm opposed to adding this *to the site* because it adds information that has no value, something that goes against the core principles of how these sites work.

Also, this would change the overall tone on the site in a  way I think isn't appropriate, at least not for SO. I much prefer the present cool "it's about the content, not the user" professionalism - remember, professionals are the life blood of every site in the network. Also, there is ample space on the user profile to [express oneself](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52443/welbog).

However, I see nothing speaking against doing this (or the general possibility to show off some gold badges) in one's own  flair as an optional extra.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe just having a free-form title field would also mean certain persons wouldn't feel the need to change their user names all the time. We could thus avoid rendering comment threads incomprehensible for mere mortals who are not learned in the ways of the BOG.

Comment: Are you saying there _is_ a possiblity to see former user names, or are you saying that for me as a mere mortal there is none?

Comment: Well, if you have a comment thread where someone addresses @TonyThePony, but you see no TonyThePony commenting, it's a fair guess that *someone* in there has changed there name in between times...